# Setting Document Properties while saving individual sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I'm not familiar with VBA at all so this has me stumped, hoping someone can help.

I have a template on a sharepoint server that is working correctly.  In order to save the xlsm file with the server document properties, I have a command button which runs the following:

```
Sub UpdateDB()
For Each Prop In ThisWorkbook.ContentTypeProperties
If Prop.Name = "Name" Then
Prop.Value = Range("B8").Value
End If
Next Prop
Filename = Range("B59").Value
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Filename, FileFormat:=52
End Sub
```

This is working well.

I now have another template which I want to do a similar thing but there are some complications:

1. I have several worksheets which I would like saved as individual files containing only the said worksheet.
2. The document properties for each file should different, based on a cell in each worksheet.

Now I have managed to setup point 1 and it's working OK using the following code:

```
Sub NewSub()
Worksheets("EMP1").Activate
Filename = Range("B1").Value
Dim wb as Workbook
Application.ActiveSheet.Copy
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
With wb
.SaveAs Filename:=Filename, FileFormat:=52
End With
End Sub
```

This is working well but if I try adding in code to set the Document Properties, it doesn't work, it won't carry them through to the new file.  I have tried adding the code which sets the document properties after line 2 and I have tried adding it also after line 7; it doesn't throw an error but it doesn't set any document properties either.  Any help on this would be much appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: How about saving the entire workbook in a `saveas` and looping through all worksheets to delete the ones you don't need?

Comment: The only thing is I need about 50 sheets from the workbook saved individually so I'm guessing deleting them after saving would prevent additional sheets from being saved?

Comment: How are you setting the properties? May I see the code?

Comment: Yes it's the same code that's in the top code box

Comment: Can anyone offer any further input?